# Cannot read property 'navTo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying do a navigation button in my sapui5 aplication deployed on Fiori

```
_onPageNavButtonPress: function () {
        var oHistory = History.getInstance();
        var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

        if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
            window.history.go(-1);
        } else {
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.navTo("default", true);
        }

    },
```

But when I click in the nave button in the console show Cannot read property 'navTo' of undefined

Comment: Apparently the oRouter is undefined. Is this method part of a controller inside a component? Are you sure that the "this" is bound correctly (i.e. it points towards your component)?

Comment: Yes, this method is part of a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Below is the new code

```
onInit: function(){
          var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        },

        onBack: function(){
        var oHistory = sap.ui.core.routing.History.getInstance();
        var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
        window.history.go(-1);
        },
```

Comment: It's unclear how the given code would solve the issue. You just removed the `getRouterFor` from the back navigation handler. `oRouter` would still be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you that `this` points to the correct scope.
If I am not wrong, when an event is fired, `this` points to the Component scope.

Something like this works for me in this snippet: https://jsbin.com/doxopodule/edit?html,output

```
onInit: function() {
    this.oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this.getView());
},

_onPageNavButtonPress: function () {
    var oHistory = History.getInstance();
    var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

    if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
        window.history.go(-1);
    } else {
        this.oRouter.navTo("default", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I get an error ReferenceError: UIComponent is not defined

Comment: Actually, event handlers `this` context is bound by default to the Controller.  @RubensCesar you are getting UIComponent as undefined probably because you did not declare it in the [sap.ui.define](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define) call.

Comment: Obviously you should declare UIComponent at the beginin to call it like I did. If not, you can call it directly as `sap.ui.core.UIComponent`.
Anyway, I'm glad to see that what you marked as solution is basically my snippet... call the Router in the onInit event and use it then in your `onBack` event...

Could you explain me why you are getting the previous hash if you don't evaluate it in the IF statements then? If you don't do so as I explain you in my snippet it will probably fail when navigating back after a deep linking navigation...